# How to limit the size of the container at the end of the screen? Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

My container is popping the screen if I do not seven a height for it, but I wanted it to be at the end of the screen automatically, how can I do that?
[image]

```
new Container(
  //height: 500.0,
  child: RefreshIndicator(
    child: GridView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      primary: true,
      //physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 4, mainAxisSpacing: 4.0, crossAxisSpacing: 4.0),
      itemCount: contacts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return CardItem(
          item: index,
          contacts: contacts,
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _selectedItem = contacts[index].name == _selectedItem
                  ? null : contacts[index].name;
            });
          },
          selected: _selectedItem == contacts[index].name,
        );
      },
    ),
    onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of Mediaquery:

```
new Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  child: RefreshIndicator(
    child: GridView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      primary: true,
      //physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 4, mainAxisSpacing: 4.0, crossAxisSpacing: 4.0),
      itemCount: contacts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return CardItem(
          item: index,
          contacts: contacts,
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _selectedItem = contacts[index].name == _selectedItem
                  ? null : contacts[index].name;
            });
          },
          selected: _selectedItem == contacts[index].name,
        );
      },
    ),
    onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your container inside SingleChildScrollView as

```
new SingleChildScrollView(child: new Container(
//height: 500.0,
child: RefreshIndicator(
child: GridView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  primary: true,
  //physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 4, mainAxisSpacing: 4.0, crossAxisSpacing: 4.0),
  itemCount: contacts.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return CardItem(
      item: index,
      contacts: contacts,
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _selectedItem = contacts[index].name == _selectedItem
              ? null : contacts[index].name;
        });
      },
      selected: _selectedItem == contacts[index].name,
    );
  },
),
onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
),
),scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,)
```